# Laravel 5.0 masking routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, controllers, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel world (using 5.0) and I'm learning how to route.
I have this route

```
Route::get('users/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

and the `UserController`

```
public function showProfile($id)
    {
         return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
```

everything works fine and the generated url  is e.g. localhost:8000/users/1.

It is possible to mask this route, having instead something like localhost:8000/users/profile, making the query under the hood?
Thank you all

Comment: You should use separate routes for **a** user and **the** user. By that I mean, the route `/user/profile` should handle the logged in user, while `/user/{id}` should only ever handle a single User, as specified by that ID.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see your point. My problem is that even for the logged in user, I don't want him to be able to see his id, I mean eg users/2

Comment: basically that number is the identifier for the user..if you expect to mask it with profile you have to then pass is as query string but again i guess you dont want that so you can submit a post request to the user/profile with specifying the required param and in controller return the record

Comment: @Daitarn Right, which is fine; a logged in User accessing `/user/profile` would see his information, and not his ID. If you **never** want a user to see any User's ID, then you're going to have to use a different attribute in your route, like `email` or `slug` or something, so long as it's unique.

Comment: Also, if your logged in user has the ID of 1, and they try to access `/user/1`, you'd simply redirect them to `/user/profile.`: `if($id == Auth::user()->id) { return redirect("/user/profile"); }`

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis... I'll go for slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to simply pull in the authenticated user:

```
Route::get('users/profile', 'UserController@showProfile');



public function showProfile()
{
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `$id` type.

```
public function showProfile($id) {
    if(is_numeric($id)) {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    } else {
        // Profile page.
        return view('user.profile_page');
    }
}
```